# How do I create a grid in python with different values?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a 4X4 grid in python where the last two rows contain the same numbers as the first two rows.

The end result should be exactly this:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

The goal is to make a game where the above grid is traversable. I've tried list comprehensions and concatenating two lists and it's not producing the right answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating two lists should work. The code for concatenating two lists

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
l3 = [l1 , l2];
l4 = l3+l3
print l4
```

should yield `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]`